# Can't import urilib.request in atom-runner

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, atom-editor

My OS is ubuntu 14.04 
Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html=urlopen("https://github.com/")
print(html.read())
```

And in ATOM with atom-runner I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ryan/PYTHON/runnertest.py", line 1, in <module>
from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

I have set the config of ATOM like this

```
runner:
python: "/usr/bin/python3"
```

and when I import other modules like random, there is nothing wrong.

But when I run this code in Sublimetext3 with SublimeREPL(I set it before to run python3) It's OK

So what is the problem?.?
THX!!

Answer (score 1):

nailed it by change the config into:

```
'runner':
  'scopes':
    'python':'python3'
```